# Lost all the "memory" of SQL developer, can it be retrieved?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I had several test instances already set up in SQL developer. Accidentally I deleted the jre folder in sqldeveloper folder, as well as the java jdk folders, so I was having issues accessing sql developer. I downloaded java jdk again and undeleted(retrieved) the jre folder .

When I tried to open sql developer again, it asked me to provide a jdk path, so I provided the jdk folder I downloaded, but it was giving me the error

> "Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine Located at path...."

so I searched on Stack overflow how to fix that and I found the file product.conf in folder

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\19.1.0

in that file, I commented out the SetJavaHome part (as it seems the jdk path I had given was wrong). So I was able to open sql developer eventually, but everything was lost, I mean, all the instances I had set up disappeared, it's like I downloaded SQL developer for the first time.

Is there a way to retrieve everything?

Comment: Just redownload again from oracle.com and use that vs trying to fix this. It'll pick up the settings from this on start.

Comment: @KrisRice should I delete sql developer first , before redownloading?

Comment: I'd download. unzip into a new folder. startup make sure it works, then nuke the borked installed one.

Comment: @KrisRice I did that but still...all the database configurations lost